# .bind("ended") event doesn't fire when user comes back to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, safari

I have one `<audio>` element on a page, and multiple Play buttons that trigger different sounds. I use JS to replace the `src` of the `<audio>` element.

When the user clicks a Play button, the script adds a `playing` class on it, removes `playing` class on the other Play buttons if needed, replaces the `src` of the player and launches the audio. If the user clicks a Play button when it already has the `playing` class, the scripts stops the audio and removes the class. When the sounds ends, the script must remove all `playing` classes.

Here's my HTML:

```
<audio id="player">
    <source id="mp3Source" src="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source id="oggSource" src="" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Here's the JS:

```
var player = $('#player')[0];
var mp3Source = $('#mp3Source');
var oggSource = $('#oggSource');

$('body').on('click touchend', '.play-btn', function(ev) {
    var e = ev.originalEvent;
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.play-btn').not(this).removeClass("playing");

    if ($(this).hasClass("playing")) {
        player.pause();
    } else {
        var newSource = $(this).attr('data-sound-source');

        mp3Source.attr('src', newSource +'.mp3');
        oggSource.attr('src', newSource +'.ogg');

        player.load();
        player.play();
    }

    $(this).toggleClass("playing");
});

$('#player').bind("ended", function(){
    $(".play-btn").removeClass('playing');
});
```

This works just fine and does exactly what I want.
But there's one **very annoying** issue: in Safari (both OS X and iOS), when the user leaves the page and then comes back to it hitting the Back button of their browser, the `ended` event doesn't fire anymore if they play a sound, so the `playing` class isn't removed at all.

It works in Chrome because, unlike Safari, Chrome reloads the whole page when the user clicks the Back button.

Does anyone have any idea what causes this annoying behavior, and how I could fix it?

Thanks !